# Why does Google say my password is weak when I only added a division sign after a bunch of random stuff?

Tags: passwords, google

I noticed something very interesting after trying to charge my password for a Google account of mines, it seems strange.

I went to the Google security control panel and selected to change my password typing in 37 characters of random junk, following every rule of good password security then I got to the part which I added the division sign (`÷`) it errored and gave a message that the symbol wasn't allow, but the password strength meter changed from strong to weak.

Why, my password was very strong, how can a simple division (`÷`) sign make it weak?

<sub>Can't reveal the password for security reasons.</sub>

Answer (score 6):

There's no cryptographic reason why adding a character would make it weak. Most likely, this is a programming oversight. In particular, if the symbol is not allowed, it may not be sending the (invalid) password to the strength-analyzing routine which then reads out the default strength, which is weak.